# NoSuchMethodError AttributePath.isPartOfCollectionElement() - Hibernate

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate-ogm

I am trying to upgrade to OGM 5.1.0.Final and I am using Spring as well. The pom is listed below -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.olp</groupId>
    <artifactId>Infra2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>Infra2</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <cxf.version>3.1.5</cxf.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-bom</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>

            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--           For JAX-WS CXF dependencies & Spring integration           -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
       <!-- portion omitted for brevity -->
    </build>

</project>
```

I am getting the following exception while running the JUnits -
(bottom of stack)

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.boot.model.source.spi.AttributePath.isPartOfCollectionElement()Z
at org.hibernate.ogm.boot.model.naming.impl.OgmImplicitNamingStrategy.transformAttributePath(OgmImplicitNamingStrategy.java:24) ~[hibernate-ogm-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl.determineBasicColumnName(ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column.redefineColumnName(Ejb3Column.java:279) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column.initMappingColumn(Ejb3Column.java:234) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column.bind(Ejb3Column.java:206) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column.buildImplicitColumn(Ejb3Column.java:695) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column.buildColumnFromAnnotation(Ejb3Column.java:515) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column.buildColumnFromAnnotation(Ejb3Column.java:471) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.ColumnsBuilder.extractMetadata(ColumnsBuilder.java:129) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:1658) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:911) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:738) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:245) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:222) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:265) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:135) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernateOgmPersistence.java:96) ~[hibernate-ogm-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
... 47 common frames omitted
```

Any pointers on what's going wrong here ? Tried following  http://hibernate.org/ogm/documentation/getting-started/  ( except jta ) but couldn't manage to get past the issue.

Comment: Remove all the bom import and leave only the spring boot one. That contains all the others as well. And you need to align the hibernate bom with the spring boot hibernate version (probably 5.2).

Comment: @Deinum, worked on the pom a bit, to reduce the redundant dependencies . But this is the minimum I need, to be able to build the project. The error is still there. Updated my original post with the revised pom & corresponding error stack.

Answer (score 4):

Hibernate OGM 5.1.0.Final only supports Hibernate ORM 5.1.x. Currently, we don't have an OGM version supporting ORM 5.2

I think you probably have an ORM 5.2 dependency. The Dependency Hierarchy view of Eclipse might help you to figure out from where it comes from.

Comment: I just downgraded OGM to 5.0.4.Final in the above pom and I am able to successfully run my testcases. Even in the above pom , I see  hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar  dependency coming in. I don't see anything with orm 5.2. Any further suggestions ?

Answer (score 3):

Well finally resolved the issue by taking clues from Guillaume's tips above. It appears that the dependency management introduces ORM dependency of 5.0.2.Final , which is insufficient in this case. I had to override and bump up the hibernate-core dependency to 5.1.5.Final , as in -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <!-- Override to 5.1.5 -->
    <version>5.1.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

The final pom looks like this -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.olp</groupId>
    <artifactId>Infra2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>Infra2</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <cxf.version>3.1.5</cxf.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-bom</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-backward-codecs</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!--           For JAX-WS CXF dependencies & Spring integration           -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <!-- portion omitted for brevity -->
    </build>

</project>
```

Notice that I had to include lucene-backward-codecs as well to make the search working.